# Endless errors with try to make a functions works from header file into cpp file

Tags: c++, class, header

```
#ifndef LibraryUser_h
#define LibraryUser_h

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class LibraryUser {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string email;
    int idnumber;
public:
    LibraryUser(string name, string email, int idnumber);
    LibraryUser();
    void addnewuser();
    string getName();
    string getEmail();
    int getIdnumber();
    void setName(string name);
    void setEmail(string email);
    void setIdnumber(int idnumber);
};

#endif
```

my cpp

```
#include "LibraryUser.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

LibraryUser(string name, string email, int idnumber) {
    this->name = name;
    this->email = email;
    this->idnumber = idnumber;
};
void setName(string name) {
    name = name;
}
void setEmail(string email) {
    email = email;
}
void setIdnumber(int idnumber) {
    idnumber = idnumber;
}

void addnewuser() {

    string objectname;
    cout << "Enter name of object.";
    cin >> objectname;
    cout << "Enter the name of the user you would like to add:";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter the email for the user.";
    cin >> email;
    cout << "Enter the idnumber for the user: ";
    cin >> idnumber;
    LibraryUser objectname(name, email, idnumber);

}
```

Im just getting a bunch of errors and I'm struggling to fix it even with the help of ai.

I'm attempting to use user input to make an object but as it is my first time using header files I'm running into a few issues. The errors I'm getting are expected ')' before name on the fifth in the cpp file and then all the variables used in the makenewuser function is not getting the not declared error even though the constructor initializes all of them.

Comment: Start by using the full name of the function you're defining: `LibraryUser::LibraryUser(string name,string email,int idnumber)`

Comment: A side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) (especially in H files).

Comment: Don't rephrase the error especially if you don't understand it. Post the complete error message in the question. BTW what is fifth? If you meant a file line, the both files have only blank fifth lines.

Comment: By fifth I meant the first line of the cpp code

Answer (score 1):

In your `.cpp` file you need to provide the fully-qualified names of the functions you are defining. For example, your constructor definition needs to be:

```
LibraryUser::LibraryUser(string name, string email, int idnumber) {
    this->name = name;
    this->email = email;
    this->idnumber = idnumber;
}
```

The same is true for the other member functions as well, as in

```
void LibraryUser::setName(string name) {
    name = name;
}
```

etc.

Comment: Now Im getting the no declaration matches error when I do this.

Comment: Where? And what is the *exact* text of the error message?

Comment: Every line that I changed with LibraryUser::Functionname. Error: C:\Users\jamwe\OneDrive\Documents\Task\Library Class Final Assignment\LibraryUser.cpp|13|error: no declaration matches 'int LibraryUser::setEmail(std::__cxx11::string)'|

Comment: The error message suggests that you *declared* the function in the `.h` file as being a `void` function, but your *definition* of the function is specified to return an `int`. Did you maybe remove `void` when you added `LibraryUser::`?

Comment: yes but i got error with void do i change it in h file

Comment: Your header file looks fine to me. Make sure in the `.cpp` file that the signature of the `setEmail` function matches what's in the header. It should look like this: `void LibraryUser::setEmail(string email) {`.

Comment: Now im back to this error on everyline with the LibraryUser: :C:\Users\jamwe\OneDrive\Documents\Task\Library Class Final Assignment\LibraryUser.cpp|5|multiple definition of `LibraryUser::LibraryUser(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)'|

Comment: Have you changed your `.h` file at all? The only way I can see for you getting that error on that line of the `.cpp` is if there is an implementation in the header.

Comment: No i didnt change it in anyway;/ Do u have discord by chance? So I could send maybe a ss

Comment: Sorry, I'm not on discord.